# Python IDLE (2.7): multi-tabbing not working

Tags: python, tabs, ide

I'm having a problem with the Python IDLE. If I try to tab in multiple lines `(Mark lines+Press [Tab])` it just replaces the lines, and doesn't tab them in. If I try to tab the out `(Mark lines+Press [Tab+Shift])` the region will turn white while marked. If I try to tab in a single line `(Press [Tab])` it tabs way too far (modified 5 spaces, tabs about 20). If I try to tab out a single line `(Press [Tab+Shift])`, nothing happens. Is there another one having this issue, or an idea to fix it?
Caps and Numlock didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tab (indent) multiple lines in IDLE use `CTRL + ]` (The `]` key on the keyboard) .

To tab them in the other direction (to decrease the indentation - dedent) , use `CTRL + [` . .

Comment: Glad to hear I could be of help :)